# Mysql_insert_id with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, mysql-insert-id

I have a couple of tables (mySQL) that i would like to update with the help of Doctrine. The products table id is auto-incrementing, and here's a brief description on what I would like to do:

```
    $prod = new Products();
    $prod->type = '0';

    $categ = new CategoriesToProducts();
    $categ->cat = '111';
    $categ->product = $prod->id;

    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
    $conn->flush();
```

How can I do this while using flush? Using a regular save is an alternative, but there will be multiple transactions while doing such. 
I have tried to find a Mysql_insert_id version for doctrine, but without any luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find some information: http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/2_0/en/basic-mapping#identifiers-/-primary-keys